# C# Console App, pass multiple parameters to custom ILogger

Tags: c#, .net-core, console, ilogger

Searching I've not found the answer I'm looking for.  I will only put code snippets here to help ask my question, supplying ALL of the code would not be executable without the entire system.

I'm using the built-in logging in C# to log to Windows Event Viewer and/or the Console.  I also wanted to write to a file but not third-party logging, so I wrote my own simple logger that logs the same data to files and works.

My appsettings.json as a second for some configuration parameters like a working folder.  I also have a folder path for the logger.  What I would like to be able to do is use the same holder path from the setting and not have 2.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "WorkingFolderPath": "C:\\mypath\\",
    "HeartbeatIntervalMinutes": 0, // This is seconds when in debug mode.
    "FileRetryDelayMinutes": 1,
    "PingTimeoutMilliseconds": 200
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Error",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
    },
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": true,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "FileLog": {
      "Options": {
        "FolderPath": "C:\\mypath\\",
        "RetentionDays": 5
      },
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you see in this file I have a "WorkingFolderPath" setting I'd like to use that as my path in my "FileLog" logger and not have to specify a path there as well.

Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
                {
                    SourceName = "FreshIQAppMessagingService"
                });
                logging.AddFileLogger(options =>
                {
                    context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging").GetSection("FileLog").GetSection("Options").Bind(options);
                });
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
            {
                config
                    .SetBasePath(ApplicationPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<Configuration>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
                services.AddHostedService<Service1>();
                services.AddHostedService<Service2>();
                services.AddHostedService<Service3>();
                services.AddHostedService<Service4>();
            });
```

Here it's getting the options and passing them in.  What I've not been able to figure out is how to change my classes so that I can send in the "WorkingFolderPath" from the top of the appsettings instead of the one with the options with the FileLog logger.

```
logging.AddFileLogger(options =>
                    {
                        context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging").GetSection("FileLog").GetSection("Options").Bind(options);
                    });
```

FileLoggerExtensions.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace FreshIQAppMessaging.Logging
{
    public static class FileLoggerExtensions
    {
        public static ILoggingBuilder AddFileLogger(this ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder, Action<FileLoggerOptions> configure)
        {
            loggingBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, FileLoggerProvider>();
            loggingBuilder.Services.Configure(configure);

            return loggingBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

FileLoggerProvider.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.IO;

namespace FreshIQAppMessaging.Logging
{
    [ProviderAlias("FileLog")]
    public class FileLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        public readonly FileLoggerOptions Options;
        public FileLoggerProvider(IOptions<FileLoggerOptions> options)
        {
            Options = options.Value;

            if (!Directory.Exists(Options.FolderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Options.FolderPath);
            }
        }

        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            return new FileLogger(this);
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

FileLogger.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;

namespace FreshIQAppMessaging.Logging
{
    public class FileLogger : ILogger
    {
        protected readonly FileLoggerProvider _fileLoggerProvider;

        public FileLogger(FileLoggerProvider fileLoggerProvider)
        {
            _fileLoggerProvider = fileLoggerProvider;
        }

        public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            return logLevel != LogLevel.None;
        }

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
            {
                return;
            }

            // Clean up old log files
            var logFiles = Directory.GetFiles(_fileLoggerProvider.Options.FolderPath, "*-MyApp.log");
            foreach (var logFilePath in logFiles)
            {
                var logFileName = new FileInfo(logFilePath).Name;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(logFileName.Substring(0, 8), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var logFileDate))
                {
                    if (logFileDate.AddDays(_fileLoggerProvider.Options.RetentionDays) < DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        File.Delete(logFilePath);
                    }
                }
            }

            var fullFilePath = $"{_fileLoggerProvider.Options.FolderPath}\\{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}-MyApp.log";
            var logRecord = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")} [{logLevel.ToString()}] {formatter(state, exception)} {(exception != null ? exception.StackTrace : "")}";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fullFilePath, true))
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(logRecord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FileLoggerOptions.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace FreshIQAppMessaging.Logging
{
    public  class FileLoggerOptions
    {
        public virtual string? FolderPath { get; set; }
        public virtual int RetentionDays { get; set; } = 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically don't want to include custom options for your logger inside the `Logging` section. Most people do something like this instead:

```json
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "WorkingFolderPath": "C:\\mypath\\",
    ...
  },
  "FileLog": {
    "FolderPath": "C:\\mypath\\",
    "RetentionDays": 5
  },
  "Logging": {
    ...
    "FileLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You didn't share your options class but I assume you have a property on it named `FolderPath`. You could then configure your file logger like this:

```cs
logging.Services.Configure<FileLoggerOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("FileLog"));
logging.AddFileLogger(options =>
{
    options.FolderPath = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:WorkingFolderPath"];
});
```

You can now remove the `FolderPath` property from the `FileLog` object in the `appsettings.json` file since that value will be set using this line when adding the file logger:

```cs
options.FolderPath = builder.Configuration["AppSettings:WorkingFolderPath"];
```

The options would then look like this:

```json
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "WorkingFolderPath": "C:\\mypath\\",
    ...
  },
  "FileLog": {
    "RetentionDays": 5
  },
  "Logging": {
    ...
    "FileLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've written a similar logging provider in the [Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging/tree/main/src/Elmah.Io.Extensions.Logging) repository and I copied some of the code from there. I tried mapping it to your original code in the question, but there might be something that doesn't match exactly. I hope that you still see the intent behind what I'm trying. You can look inside this repository for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yes sorry the FileLoggerOptions.cs does have a RetensionDays and FolderPath (updated the question with it)  I kind of would like to keep the RetensionDays with the Logging/FileLog as it pertains to it specifically is there a reason to not do this?

A side question is it bad practice to open write to the file with every call should it be creating the stream writer as part of the constructor and destroy it later?

Comment: I just mixed what I had and what you recommended and this works for what I want but would still like your feedback on the stream writer that I asked in the previous comment.

                logging.AddFileLogger(options =>
                {
                    context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging").GetSection("FileLog").GetSection("Options").Bind(options);
                    options.FolderPath = context.Configuration["AppSettings:WorkingFolderPath"];
                });

Comment: Since writing the answer I did actually find a couple of logger implementations that have settings within their config object beneath `Logging`. So, I guess that would be ok. As for writing to the file I would look at how this is already implemented in various frameworks. Like for NLog here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/Targets/FileTarget.cs. You could also find one of the third-party file loggers implemented for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (available on NuGet) to see how they have done it. Opening and closing the file on every write doesn't sound like a good idea :)